# SP2013 - API for Administration

Tags: 2013, administration

We are in the process of standing up a web application that would handle provisioning of SP2013 site colleciton and management of its life cycle (lock/unlock, manage permission,  quota, etc..). The application would be hosted outside of the SharePoint farm and we are trying to figure out the best API to use to communicate with SharePoint. Is there one API (CSOM or Webservice) that would let us manage administration of the sites remotely? Or do we have to write custom WCF services deployed on the farm that would call the server object model?

Btw, the instance of the Sharepoint is on-prem.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three choices:

1. Use the deprecated, but still present, Admin.asmx web service, specifically [CreateSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/administration.admin.createsite%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
2. Spoof Central Administration POST requests and reverse engineer the requests for the appropriate page (yeah I know how it sounds, but we're doing it for a few things when there are no other ways).
3. Write a custom service as you hinted.

Side note: This would be SO MUCH easier as a SharePoint Application page. Consider hosting it in SharePoint (yeah defeats the purpose I know but..)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a service. The SharePoint Client API (allows for creating sites and site collections. You will need to ensure you have the permissions for the client application setup correctly.

Comment: Actually the Client API cannot go higher than Sites, so there's nothing to create them from (cannot access Web Applications). This cannot be done with the COM.

Comment: http://blog.scoreman.net/2013/02/create-site-collections-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom/

Comment: Yeah, the title says SharePoint online. It is possible there with the Tenant API, which has no equivalent on premises